# NTFS compression/decompression

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, compression

I bought an ASUS E200H: Win 10 Home 64-bit; 32GB of SSD (the operating system occupies around 20GB, so only around 10GB is left for me).

After installing all the programs that I need, I had around 1GB of free space.

I was advised to perform the NTFS compression on the whole C: to save more space.

So I checked the NTFS compression for C:, and it started to run.

As it ran, I noticed that the Windows Manager says that there is less and less free space.

When it was around 200MB, i decided to stop the process, and unchecked the compression.

The process started running again, and the free space continued decreasing, and soon reached 0 bytes.

So the question is, what should I do now?..

Should I run the compression again and let it finish? Or keep it decompressed - but in this case how can I regain the free space that I had before running int this procedure?.. Or possibly compress only some folders - which yes and which no?..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Compression needs temporary space, as it is writing its result before it removes the old file. 1GB might be just to little to have multiple large files converted by multiple threads.

My recommendation is to move some GB temporarily off the disk, finish the compression, and then move it back.